# Hyperlink box (txtbox) on Access Form won't allow drop

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink, drag-and-drop

I have a MS Access form that is bound to a query in the database.  I added a textbox and added a row source to a Hyperlink datafield in the query.  When I open the form, it won't allow me to drop a file into the textbox.

Here's the deal.  When I follow this EXACT same process on a new form, it works perfectly.  That is, I open a blank form and I bind the form to some new query, let's say qryNewIdeas. Then on the blank form i add a textbox, let's say Text0.  Then, when I select Text0, I go to the data tab - row source and choose the dropdown arrow to select the hyperlink field, lets say NewIdeasAddress.  I click SAVE and open the form.  It  works PERFECTLY.

BUT, when I repeat this on an existing form (the one where I need the thing to actually work), it does nothing.  It adds and changes the textbox to a hyperlink box (I note this because of the blue underlined word that appears in the box). But it won't allow me to drop files to this location.

I tried commenting out ALL of my VBA code to try to make sure that something wasn't hindering it (say in an OnLoad event) AND I've checked all of the form and control box properties and they seem to be the same in both the existing form and the test form.

I can't determine why it works on one form and not the other; Solution needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to "the data tab - row source ..", you are in *design view*.

When you later open the form, you are in *form view*, a completely different animal which specifically prohibits design changes.

It sounds like you will have to rethink your concept.